# Dropzone.js prevents Flask from rendering template

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, flask, dropzone.js

I am using `Dropzone.js` to allow drag and drop upload of `CSV` files via a `Flask` web site. The upload process works great. I save the uploaded file to my specified folder and can then use `df.to_html()` to convert the `dataframe` into `HTML` code, which I then pass to my template. It gets to that point in the code, but it doesn't render the template and no errors are thrown. So my question is why is `Dropzone.js` preventing the render from happening?

I have also tried just return the `HTML` code from the table and not using `render_template`, but this also does not work.

**init**.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

# get the current folder
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('upload1.html')


@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():

    # set the target save path
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'uploads/')

    # loop over files since we allow multiple files
    for file in request.files.getlist("file"):

        # get the filename
        filename = file.filename

        # combine filename and path
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])

        # save the file
        file.save(destination)

        #upload the file
        df = pd.read_csv(destination)
        table += df.to_html()

    return render_template('complete.html', table=table)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=4555, debug=True)
```

upload1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.css">


<table width="500">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form action="{{ url_for('upload') }}", method="POST" class="dropzone"></form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the sample `csv` data I am uploading:

```
Person,Count
A,10
B,12
C,13
```

Complete.html

```
<html>

<body>

{{table | safe }}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the content for `complete.html`?

Comment: It's really basically just the html code for the table passed via `render_template`. I've added it the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code **does** work. Your template will be rendered and returned.

Dropzone will upload files you drag and drop into your browser 'in the background'.
**It will consume the response from the server and leave the page as is**. It uses the response from the server to know if the upload was successful.

To see this in action:

- Navigate to your page
- Open up your favourite browser dev tools; (in firefox press CTRL+SHIFT+K)
- Select the network tab
- Drag your csv into the dropzone pane and note that the request shows in the dev tools network table

Here is a screen shot from my browser. I copied your code as is from your question.

[image: Screen shot of code working]

To actually see the rendered `complete.html` you will need to add another flask endpoint and have a way to navigate to that.

For example:
in `upload1.html` add:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('upload_complete') }}">Click here when you have finished uploading</a>
```

in `init.py` change and add:

```
def upload():

    ...

        # you do not need to read_csv in upload()
        #upload the file
        #df = pd.read_csv(destination)
        #table += df.to_html()

    return "OK"
    # simply returning HTTP 200 is enough for dropzone to treat it as successful
    # return render_template('complete.html', table=table)

# add the new upload_complete endpoint
# this is for example only, it is not suitable for production use
@app.route('/upload-complete')
def upload_complete():
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'uploads/')
    table=""
    for file_name in os.listdir(target):
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
        table += df.to_html()
    return render_template('complete.html', table=table)
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I did end up adding a link. No way to have to auto render?

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** Now you can use [Flask-Dropzone](https://github.com/greyli/flask-dropzone), a Flask extension that integrates Dropzone.js with Flask. For this issue, you can set `DROPZONE_REDIRECT_VIEW` to the view you want to redirect when uploading complete.

---

**Dropzone.js use AJAX to post data**, that's why it will not give back the control to your view function.

There are two methods to redirect (or render template) when all files were complete uploading.

- You can add a button to redirect.

  `<a href="{{ url_for('upload') }}">Upload Complete</a>`
- You can add an event listener to automatic redirect page (use jQuery).

  ```
  <script>
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

  $(function() {
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");
    myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(file) {
      // Called when all files in the queue finish uploading.
      window.location = "{{ url_for('upload') }}";
    });
  })
  </script>
  ```

In view function, add an `if` statement to check whether the HTTP method was `POST`:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOADED_PATH'] = 'the/path/to/upload'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # render upload page
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for f in request.files.getlist('file'):
            f.save(os.path.join('the/path/to/upload', f.filename))
    return render_template('your template to render')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flask-Dropzone then:

```
{{ dropzone.config(redirect_url=url_for('endpoint',foo=bar)) }}
```

Comment: please complete your question to get better answers